# noHandlerFound while trying for url

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Getting the following error while I m trying for url,

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DeTester/hellot] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Following are my files,

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
 instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.sri</groupId>
 <artifactId>DeTester</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Tester Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <repositories>
 <repository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-releases</id>
    <name>Spring Releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
   <properties>
     <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
     <build>
     <finalName>DeTester</finalName>
     </build>
      </project>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.sri.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

 @Controller
 public class HelloWorldController {

  String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

   @RequestMapping("/hello")
   public ModelAndView showMessage(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    System.out.println("in controller");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
    mv.addObject("message", message);
    mv.addObject("name", name);
    return mv;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hellot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHellos(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      System.out.println("printing ra");
      return "hello";
     }
     }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


 <display-name>DeTester</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    </web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 ">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.sri.controller" />

 <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
  </beans>
```

I am getting the above error repeatedly,can I now why is that error occuring,Is it a missing o jar file or Is there any mistake in my code.please answer this as soon as possible.